# Миграция с @import на @use

Tags: vue.js, scss, импорт

Вычитал в документации sass, что со временем @import вообще [уберут](https://sass-lang.su/documentation/at-rules/import) и нужно будет использовать @use.

Для миграции установил [мигратор](https://sass-lang.su/documentation/cli/migrator). Поменял с помощью мигратора все @import на @use в файлах с расширением .scss

Мой проект на Vue. Попытался поменять импорты в файлах с расширением .vue, но столкнулся с ошибкой.

```
Error: @use rules must be written before any other rules.
```

Хотя больше в тегах стайла в этом файле ничего нет, кроме единого импорта. Вопрос такой, это вообще возможно поменять в каких-либо файлах, кроме .scss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для подключения в файлы vue необходимо было назначить alias.

```
@use '/src/assets/styles/variables' as *;`
```